# Problem with Euro formatting (123.456,78) on Microsoft Access Report

Tags: formatting

On my report in Microsoft Access for all fields I have set-up this code in Control source:

=Replace(Replace(Replace(Format(Sum([NameOfTheField]),"#,###.00"),".","*"),",","."),"*",",")

and on this way I managed to replace format "123,456.78" to "123.456,78" because I need to have Euro formatting on report.

This code works ok but problem is when some column contains zero value, then I would like to replace "0" with "-" and I don't know how to achieve this?

And help is appreciated and many thanks for prompt replys!

Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195899%28v=office.11%29.aspx) you can specify a distinct/special format for 0 values; I would at least try if "#,###.00" => "#.###,00" does not 'work'.